# ng-repeat is not working. Think there is a scope issue but not sure.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have the following div:

```
<div id="chatrooms" ng-controller="TableMsgController">
<section id="chatroom">
<div id="messages"  >
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="entry in seenMsgs">{{entry.msg}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <form action="">
     <input type="text" id="userMsg" ng-model="userMsg">
    <input type="button" class="gButton" id= "sendMsgBtn" value="Send" ng-click="sendMsg()" />

    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

And I have the following controller:

```
tables.controller('TableMsgController',function ($rootScope,$scope) {
  $scope.msgSeen = [];
  $scope.sendMsg = function () {
    //console.log("sendMsg button pushed");
    //console.log($scope.userMsg);
    $scope.msgSeen.push( {'msg':$scope.userMsg} );
   // console.log($scope.msgSeen);
};
```

The ng-repeat is not working.

Any idea why?

Z

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I can spot:

a) You're missing a closing brace on `sendMsg`:

```
tables.controller('TableMsgController',function ($rootScope,$scope) {
  $scope.msgSeen = [];
  $scope.sendMsg = function () {
    //console.log("sendMsg button pushed");
    //console.log($scope.userMsg);
    $scope.msgSeen.push( {'msg':$scope.userMsg} );
   // console.log($scope.msgSeen);
  }    <---------------------------------------------- :)
};
```

and b) you define `msgSeen` in the scope but are attempting to iterate over `seenMsgs`:

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in seenMsgs">{{entry.msg}}</li>
```

Resolve both of these and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Dyslexia at it's finest! Fixed the issues and it worked!

Comment: Great. You were lucky that I spotted those pretty quickly; it generally helps a lot to describe the error symptoms in more detail. Granted, JS is a bit of a pain, but you can pop up the console/debugger in your browser to see any error messages

Comment: There were no error messages, that was what was confusing me so much. I am just learning AngularJS  and I tried all sorts of combinations. I appreciate  the help! Thanks!